# Fetch Data into HDInsight from an existing Storage Account

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, azure-storage-account

Initially, i have created a Hadoop HDInsight Cluster in Azure with storage account. In Ambari portal, i have connected to hive warehouse and created some sample tables.
Now, I have deleted the HDInsight cluster and created a new cluster with same specs and region as of previous cluster. Storage account got connected but i can't see those tables which i have created previously.

Can someone please provide steps or a reference blog.

Comment: Have you created created HDInsight cluster with custom metastore?

Comment: I created the HDInsight on the existing storage accont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior when you create a HDInsight cluster without Custom metastore.

> Is the Hive metastore deleted when the cluster is deleted?

It depends on the type of metastore that your cluster is configured to use.

**For a default metastore:** The default metastore is part of the cluster lifecycle. When you delete a cluster, the corresponding metastore and metadata are also deleted.

**For a custom metastore:** The lifecycle of the metastore isn't tied to a cluster's lifecycle. So, you can create and delete clusters without losing metadata. Metadata such as your Hive schemas persists even after you delete and re-create the HDInsight cluster.

**Reference:** [Use external metadata stores in Azure HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-external-metadata-stores).

Comment: This document is using Azure SQL Database, can i use table from the existing stoarge account which was a part of HDinsight.

Comment: iItried the custom megastore method, created some sample table in Azure SQL Database but HIve can't fetch those table.